# What do you call a hybrid traditional/push state application?

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, design-patterns, language-agnostic

Wondering if there's a name for this technique in its various incarnations... And if there are any resources by people implementing it.

Let's say you have a page, very much like github. And with a JavaScript supported browser, you load up

```
http://www.github.com/username/project

UI and inner content load simultaneously, the pre-AJAX way
- or -
UI wrapper loads, inner content loads via AJAX
```

And it loads a static skeleton and all the modules via AJAX. Or, it could load the entire page statically.

Then you click on some navigational elements and try to visit

```
http://www.github.com/username/project/first_dir

With previously loaded UI
  Inner content navigation causes full page refresh
    - or -
  Inner content navigation causes inner content reload via page refresh
  - or -
Completely new page with UI and inner content loads, same as first example
```

At this point I know that this page could be "visited" using push state and having the inner module refresh with AJAX, keeping the overall chrome of the site static. But if for some reason JavaScript wasn't supported OR the page was loaded using a full refresh, the page would completely load statically (or partially via AJAX after the skeleton loads, like in the first URL).

What is this technique called? It seems to be like a unified model that pierces through the server's MVC model and the client's MVC model. I know it can be done with lots of elbow grease, but I was wondering if someone has already investigated this technique and developed guidelines on how to keep the two models synchronized architecturally.

Comment: Fun fact, GitHub's UI does not work with JavaScript turned off. So even though individual URLs will work with JS style routing, they do not suport the old world/no-JS model (at least not consistently).

Comment: I'm sorry, but what exactly is asked here? The name of this technique? Or where to find the guidelines of using it?

Comment: Ideally I'd like more resources on it but it's hard to search for since I don't know the name for it. A name would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I really don't know how this technique is named, but I can tell how we usually implement similar behavior in our project (based on the MVC architecture).

The point is using View Helpers (or Partials; we've chosen the former, though) to build different parts of the whole page. For example, a sidebar is built by one Helper object, a table representing a collection of some items - with another, etc. Each of this Helper can be named a mini-view of a sort, as it's responsible for representing some data in some very particular way.

Each of these helpers is ready to be called either as a standalone (then its result will be used in AJAX processor to refresh some part of the page) or as a part of more complex process (then its result is used in a form of layout template).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to raina77ow I also don't know how this is called, but we implemented exactly this awhile ago for a mobile app/webpage (which had to work in old opera/IE versions as well). What we did was first build a more or less pure HTML page which next bound **all** a tags and replace the functionality through javascript with an ajax call which retrieved the *entire* page and 'cut out' (jQuery has native functionality for this) the part which was relevant (this doesn't give the full advantage of AJAX based pages, but prevents reloading of various assets). This also prevents any complex 'synchronization' issues or API's which need to be able to return JSON **and** HTML.

Aside of that, if I take the MVC model and how we implemented in some of our applications you could look at it like this: HTML is the view (static), JS is the controller which requests through AJAX data from server side models. This makes a lot more sense than imagining a separate MVC structure for the front *and* backend.

Comment: Cutting out content from a full download seems kind of kludgey?

Comment: Oh, yes, definitely, as I said, it doesn't give the full advantage of AJAX based pages (though you still do have a lot), but keeps backward compatibility and js-less systems extremely easily supported. (And if you are using jquery you can simply request a certain element from the larger html like this `$.get('/path/to/foo.html #base'...`, which makes the cutting itself more do-able)

Answer (score 0):

Spike Brehm of Airbnb calls this the *Holy Grail*.

http://nerds.airbnb.com/weve-launched-our-first-nodejs-app-to-product